# How many competing papers can be expected for a topic?

Tags: publications

How many competing papers can be expected for a topic?

Assuming that papers should be competed for, since as in a free market, the competition should lead to better outcomes, right?

So then, when one writes papers, then how many papers may one expect to compete against? And where's the competition in: quality of research outcomes, readability of paper, quality of implementations, ...

Comment: Your framing of science and scientific publishing as a free market appears weird to me. I don't even know who you consider the competitiors in your framework.

Comment: @Roland Weird? Surely the benefits of free market should apply to science. As opposed to, what someone may expect, some "ivory tower". Journals sell rights to read publications, i.e. they're businesses. Universities compete for workforce and students. In full sense, these should be under competition in order to select the "best outcomes" as is the case with free market.

Comment: I suggest you turn your theory into a manuscript and publish it. Your comments are not sufficient to understand your framework. You don't even define "best outcomes" and you don't explain why a free market would ensure them in this specific case.

Comment: @Roland The free market with competition is the ideal regarding how resources are best allocated. Like selling bread or whatever. We have many producers of bread and they use different methods to produce bread. So then replace "bread" with "research".

Comment: Research (generally) is not a product that is sold ... I'm not an economist but you seem to simplify too much.

Comment: @Roland I think it should be, if it's not. Without competition, why would there be pressure to innovate?

Comment: Well, you are free to think so. I think I'll disagree. I don't have anything else to add. Have a nice day.

Comment: @mavavilj Some innovation could come from internal motivation (e.g., curiosity), instead of external motivation (e.g., gain recognition and impact).

Comment: @mavavilj The very idea behind tenure is to allow people to perform research without having to worry about competition all the time. And while the tenure system has many flawed aspects, I do not know anyone in academia who would like to replace it with "publish or perish" until retirement.

Comment: @mlk "I do not know anyone in academia who would like to replace it with "publish or perish" until retirement.". Isn't it obvious that no-one whose own benefit is related to some decision would not like that benefit to go away? However, as per the earlier critique, I was questioning the idea of non- free market essentially producing best outcomes, since there's no incentive to perform better than a competitor(?) I.e. that there's no chance that someone would publish a better version of said research?

Comment: @lighthousekeeper I think we can quite safely assume that people who can produce publishable research, are motivated. Therefore motivation should not be a factor for "no competition".

Comment: @mavavilj That's not logical. You said "Without competition, why would there be pressure to innovate?", and I gave a reason how innovation can take place without competition.

Comment: @mavavilj It might not be the standard in economics, but people are quite capable of making altruistic decisions that hurt them personally, but improve the general situation. And thinking in the same utilitarian vein, as long as there are topics on which no research is done, writing competing papers about the same result, just to see whose is more readable, is just a waste of time.

Comment: @lighthousekeeper Yes it can, but OTOH is it even possible to understand innovation without comparison?

Comment: @mlk But I find that this is a major selling point in science books? That's why some people pick this algebra book and not that algebra book, even when they might in essence have the same information. That's not wasted effort, that's free market.

Comment: @mavavilj Textbooks are not research. There is probably a six digit number of people who at some point might want to read an algebra textbook. In contrast, from what someone working for a big publisher once told me, if a research monograph in math sells 200 copies, it is generally considered a success. And while all undergradute classes are more than covered with textbooks, there is no book on most research topics and for many of them there never will be.

Comment: @mavavilj Comparison is not inherently competitive, but could also be driven by curiosity. A curious researcher might say: "Cool that we can do X now! What if we could also do X+Y?"

Comment: @mavavilj In addition, the internal motivation can also come from a real-world need. Cancer researchers presumably don't care about outperforming other cancer researchers as much as they care about fighting cancer.

Comment: Markets are widely believed to be a good way of allocating (some types of) scarce resources, but I don't think anyone claims they're good at anything else apart from allocating scarce resources.  What is it that you believe to be the scarce resource here?

Comment: @DanielHatton No, they're efficient at also producing best usage of all resources, because they have to match to a demand, which might call for different things. A past argument against publicly funded science is that it leads to inefficiency, because the users are not forced to meet real-world requirements, such as time limits, economical costs, changing requirements etc. What they're inefficient in is perhaps pure science, which is not motivated by "being economical". But ultimately perhaps, the reasonability of competition may depend on the field and the study in particular.

Comment: *Without competition, why would there be pressure to innovate* --- "I do not know what I may appear to the world, but to myself I seem to have been only like a boy playing on the sea-shore, and diverting myself in now and then finding a smoother pebble or a prettier shell than ordinary, whilst the great ocean of truth lay all undiscovered before me."

Comment: I'm closing this question because, as the comments show, as-is it's really just going to prompt discussion. I don't see any objective way the question as-written can be answered, except the one existing answer of "it depends" which rather suggests the question is not clearly constructed.

Answer (score 1):

> How many competing papers can be expected for a topic?

The answer entirely depends on the topic and could be anything between 1 and several tens or hundreds. Generally, there are "hot" and "cold" topics.

> Assuming that papers should be competed for, since as in a free market, the competition should lead to better outcomes, right?

The main hurdle that researchers have to face is to get their paper accepted in good venues. This is not a question of competition, but of meeting the standards imposed by the reviewers in the peer review process.

Once that papers are accepted and published, there is somewhat of a competition about impact (often measured in terms of citation counts, a somewhat problematic metric). Generally, one strives to have impact, but a high-quality paper is not guaranteed to have impact. On the contrary, an otherwise mediocre paper can have high impact if it has a unique aspect to it, like being the first to observe something that turns out to be important. Marketing also plays a role in impact.